# Rancher Desktop: How to set insecure-repositories on Windows, as set in /etc/docker/daemon.json file

Tags: windows, configuration, set, docker-daemon, rancher-desktop

I need to add this for pushing docker images to remote machine.
'{ "insecure-registries" : ["10.60.3.4:6000"] }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insecure registries can be added via rancher's wsl. Here's a solution that worked for me.

In Command Prompt or Powershell execute

```
wsl -d rancher-desktop -e vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

then add the registry/ies you require like that:

```
{
    "insecure-registries": [  
       "url-registry-url"
    ]
}
```

Source (besides others): https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/discussions/870#discussioncomment-2673125

Comment: I am able to add insecure repositories thanks.